# Github Actions: Checkout@v3 on private repo in org: not found

Tags: github-actions

I am creating a private org and trying to create reusable workflows within my private repositories by checking out one private repo, then running a workflow within it.

I am always met with the same error:

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEymF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dBLP.png)

Pipeline code:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]


jobs:
  NET_6_Pipeline:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with: 
          repository: <ORGNAME>/<REPONAME>
          token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
          path: reusable-actions
      - uses: ./reusable-actions/BuildNET.yml@main
        with:
          secrets: inherit
```

I created the token with quite literally every permission, and placed it in my org secrets (we have paid so can utilize org secrets in private repos)

[Pipeline Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wQL2.png)

Comment: the clone isn't failing -- your reusable action is -- you need to put it into a directory with an `action.yml` and then `uses: ./reusable-actions/path/to/that/directory`

Comment: it is very much failing on the checkout action @anthonysottile check the last image I edited in

Comment: Does your repo have a `main` branch? Or a `master` branch?

Comment: @VonC main branch

Comment: just tried changing default branch to master, also did not work. Same exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue:

My problem was that I was using a PAT that I created under my personal account, but had not enabled PAT access in my org.

Solution:

1. Go to Organization Home Page
2. Click Personal Access Tokens in the left menu, scroll down to find it under Third-part access
3. Click settings under that
4. Allow Fine Grained access tokens
5. create a new PAT under my profile, and set the Resource Owner as my org